# AJAX - preflight 400 error

Tags: jquery, ajax, cors

In my app, I am getting a preflight error on the second AJAX call when making the following two-step call:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'https://podio.com/oauth/token',
    data: {
        'grant_type': 'app',
        'app_id': '#####',
        'app_token': '#####',
        'client_id': '#####',
        'redirect_uri': '#####',
        'client_secret': '#####'
    }
}).done(function(response){
    $.ajax({
        type:'PUT',
        contentType: "application/json",
        headers: {'Authorization': 'OAuth2 ' + response.access_token},
        url:'https://api.podio.com/item/1/value/142784383',
        data: JSON.stringify({"values": "doofus@test.com"})
    }).done(function(response){
        console.log(response)
    }).fail(function(error){
        console.log(error)
    })
})
```

The error in Chrome (with the CORS Toggle browser extension on) is as follows:

> jquery.min.js:4 OPTIONS https://api.podio.com/item/1 400 ()
>   test.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://api.podio.com/item/1/value/142784383. Response for preflight
>   has invalid HTTP status code 400

and Safari logs

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (HTTP/2.0 403)
```

referring to `https://api.podio.com/item/1/value/142784383`

Although I've used AJAX calls like this plenty of times for my own apps, I'm a little unfamiliar with some of the nuances of engaging with external APIs.  Any insight into the causes and solutions to this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but you need to send: `JSON.stringify({ values: doofus@test.com })`

Comment: @KobyDouek Don't think so, the content type means json itself will work.

Comment: @Achshar Yeah, but this is the correct syntax anyway

Comment: JSON.stringify({"values": "doofus@test.com"}) seems right. In your code the email needs to be in quotes.

Comment: @skwidbreth When the content type is something exotic, browser sends an options (preflight) request. Your api needs to handle this OPTIONS request. So make sure the server sends a 200 on an options request along with a acceptable content type header as well. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: @Achshar in this context, would I set that with `beforeSend`?

Comment: @skwidbreth I added an answer. That might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you define the content type to be application/json. The thing with that is that when the content type is anything other than the simple text/html (and a couple of others) the browser sends an OPTIONS request to make sure the server is expecting the content type.

The server then has to send a couple of headers. You might be familiar with `access-control-allow-origin: *` but the server also needs to tell the browser what header fields it's willing to accept. For that the server needs to send a

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers: Content-Type
```

This tells the browser that the client can send a content type header in the actual request. So you need to make sure that the server is not only accepting and returning 200 on an OPTIONS request but also sending the two headers mentioned above.

In reply to your comment, you dont need to do anything on the client. The server needs to send those headers.

[More](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: Thank you - that really clears this up.  I don't have control over the server in this case (it's a vendor that we're engaging with), so it seems that I need to look into this process a little more carefully.

Comment: If it's a vendor and they are expecting the request then they must also already be sending the headers as well. I suggest you make the request in a Postman like software and make sure it works regardless. The 403 you mentioned reeks of an authentication token issue.

Comment: yes, you've helped me crack this! This actually appears to be a permissions issue - I think that we need to get the trust level of the api key upgraded.